# Loose WHERE statements

Tags: sql, mysql

The following 3 queries would return the same record:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '1'
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '1 foo'
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '1 123'
```

It seems like the characters after the space in the quotes are ignored.

Is that a feature and what would be the purpose of it?

Comment: id is string or integer column?

Comment: @Sergey, it's an integer column.

Comment: look at The Scrum Meister`s answer, he is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `id` is a number, when MySql casts the string to a number they all yield the same result: the number `1`.

```
SELECT CAST('1' AS SIGNED) a,
  CAST('1 foo' AS SIGNED) b,
  CAST('1 123' AS SIGNED) c
```

Results:

```
a | b | c
1 | 1 | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) of the mysql reference says that mysql implicitly casts strings to numbers and vice versa. This example of the page illustrates this :

```
mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 0 > 'x6';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6';
        -> 1
```

In your case, all your string are implicitly casted to the number 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'string' you have supplied is getting converted to a number, as the id field is probably an integer.
If this is the case, then the conversion will stop when it reaches a non numeric character, which is what the space is. Therefore all the strings convert to a numeric 1 and return the same row.